# Excel - Multiple Cell Calculation

Tags: excel, vba, formula, calculation

I'm a teacher and trying to create a mark sheet the problem I have is that assignments are marked using different schemes (i.e. % [1 - 100], Level [1 -4], Letter Grade [F - A]). The problem I have is that I only want to report using one marking scheme and need to convert or calculate the other marking schemes based on the scheme there is it is marked.

I've made an excel worksheet which contains a student names and assignments. The sheet then has 3 other columns, one representing each scheme "Letter", "Level", Percentage a column for each scheme. Now, at any given time there is going to be a value in one of the 'scheme' columns - I need excel to automatically or by macro calculate the appropriate value into the other cells.

For example, there are three assignments each marked with a different scheme on the same sheet.

```
Assignment 1 - %
Assignment 2 - Level 
Assignment 3 - Letter Grade
```

How can I get excel to check which mark value exists and then populate/calculate the other two the corresponding values.

Mike got 80% (%) on Assignment 1, but I want excel to populate the level column and letter column with the corresponding values at the same time Level 3 on Assignment 2 excel to calculate corresponding percentage and letter and at the same time for a Letter A on Assignment 3 the corresponding % and level should be calculated.

Don't know if this is possible or makes sense, but I tried VLOOKUP and was not successful because I have to do it all manually - I'm aiming for an automated process.

Sorry if it is not clear or confusing...but I've been at this for two days with no luck and not even sure if what I'm doing is possible.

Answer (score 0):

of course it should be first assessed the *translation* of one rating system to the other and then assume those algorithms to shift between rating grades types

one of the possible approaches could be the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim grades As Variant, levels As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim index As Double

    grades = Array("F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A")
    levels = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

    For Each cell In Intersect(Range("A:C"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        Select Case cell.Column
            Case 1 '%
                index = cell.value / 100
                cell.Offset(, 1).value = GetRate(index, levels)
                cell.Offset(, 2).value = GetRate(index, grades)
            Case 2 ' Level
                index = InStr(Join(levels, ""), cell.value) / Len(Join(levels, ""))
                cell.Offset(, -1).value = index * 100
                cell.Offset(, 1).value = GetRate(index, grades)
            Case 3
                index = InStr(Join(grades, ""), cell.value) / Len(Join(grades, ""))
                cell.Offset(, -2).value = index * 100
                cell.Offset(, -1).value = GetRate(index, levels)
        End Select
    Next
End Sub

Function GetRate(index As Double, rates As Variant)
    GetRate = rates(WorksheetFunction.Max(Round(index * (UBound(rates) - LBound(rates) + 1), 0) - 1, 0))
End Function
```

due to the simplicity of the translation algorithm it doesn't provide a bijective relationship between grading systems with different spans, but it can get you closer to your goal

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612730/why-variable-is-not-accessed-inside-a-case-statement-in-excel-vba/41613112#41613112) you may take inspiration from for "translation algorithms"

Comment: Thank you for the direction, I will try and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table like so (you can add more rows if you need to define +/- scores like "B+", etc.). The key here is sort the table ascending by %, with each row being the *minimum* score needed for the corresponding Level/Letter Grade.

[image]

Then, you can use `VLOOKUP` formula against this table, like so to get the Level:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,$A$1:$C$7,2,TRUE)
```

And like so, to get the Letter Grade:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,$A$1:$C$7,3,TRUE)
```

[image]

This takes advantage of the `True` parameter in the VLOOKUP function, which will return an *approximate match* (and assumes data is sorted ascending). So, when you enter a value like "81%", it returns the nearest row which is *not greater than* 81%, so it will return data from row 5. Likewise, 12% will return data from row 2, 75% from row 4, etc.

And your results:

[image]

You may need to use *two* tables if you can't 1:1 map the Level/Letter Grade to a Percent row, but the idea would be the same.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I continue to search for answers on google and try different things. I know there is a way to do this in excel and am determined to make it happen. Eventually, I think this may go the route of an access database, but I want to keep things simple for now as my coding skills are not the greatest.

Comment: @Syngh does the above approach *not work* for you? If not, can you please elaborate (revise your original question with new/relevant information)?  This should work, and does not require *any* VBA programming...

Comment: thanks for the code David, my intial issue that I'm trying to solve for is this (and again I'm sorry if I don't articulate it very well). I need excel to automatically look at cells in 3 different column - once it sees a 'mark' in one of those cells I need it to automatically populate the corresponding value into the other two cell. VLookup works, but I have to insert the formula into the correct rows, I'm hoping to do it at a higher level where I don't need the VLookup as a fx in the cell and just have it run a script to execute the results.

Comment: you might consider revising your question with the following: A better explanation of what you're trying to do, screenshot or preferably pasted text example of your *inputs*, and also same for the expected *outputs/results*. it's also very helpful in most cases if you will demonstrate what you have tried so far, explaining the problems or shortcomings thereof (this helps others avoid making the same errors while assisting you).