# Why variable is not accessed inside a case statement in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel VBA function which gives the grading of a student in the B column based on the marks in the A column.  I tried with FOR NEXT and it worked fine but when I tried with DO While it showed error. Where is the issue?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim mark As Single
    Dim grade As String
    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 1
    Do While counter < 10
        counter = counter + 1
        mark = Cells(counter, 1).Value
        'To set the alignment to center
        Range("A1:B10").Select
            With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
        Select Case mark
            Case 0 To 20
            grade = "F"
            Cells(counter, 2) = grade
            Case 20 To 29
            grade = "E"
            Cells(counter, 2) = grade
            Case 30 To 39
            grade = "D"
            Cells(counter, 2) = grade
            Case 40 To 59
            grade = "C"
            Cells(counter, 2) = grade
            Case 60 To 79
            grade = "B"
            Cells(counter, 2) = grade
            Case 80 To 100
            grade = "A"
            Cells(counter, 2) = grade
            Case Else
            grade = "Error!"
            Cells(counter, 2) = grade
        End Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

You can take any values between 0 to 100 in the first 10 rows of excel sheet A column. When you run the macro the B cell gets filled with gradings.

Comment: The code you posted works just fine for me. What was the error and which line was it on?

Comment: First I got error in this line `mark = Cells(counter, 1).Value` and then when I changed it to `mark = Cells(1, 1).Value` it showed error in `Cells(counter, 2) = grade` in 3rd case statement as the mark enetred was 35. When I was replacing counter with a value it was working perfectly.

Comment: What was the *specific* error that you got?

Comment: I just remember the error no as 1041 as it was in my office PC. And you are right when I am trying my own code in home PC it is working perfectly. Than what was wrong in my office PC. I just used Option Explicit and nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code works for me. 
since you want to slop through the first 10 rows you have to set counter=0 at the beginning, or not to set it at all
furthermore you can shorten it down :

```
Private Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim mark As Single
    Dim grade As String
    Dim counter As Integer

    Range("A1:B10").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Do While counter < 10
        counter = counter + 1
        mark = Cells(counter, 1).Value
        'To set the alignment to center
        Select Case mark
            Case 0 To 19
                grade = "F"
            Case 20 To 29
                grade = "E"
            Case 30 To 39
                grade = "D"
            Case 40 To 59
                grade = "C"
            Case 60 To 79
                grade = "B"
            Case 80 To 100
                grade = "A"
            Case Else
                grade = "Error!"
        End Select
        Cells(counter, 2) = grade
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: as you see I also 1) moved the `HorizontalAlignment` setting outside the loop, since it doesn't need to be set at every iteration! 2) corrected `Case 0 To 20` to `Case 0 To 19` no to overlap with subsequent `Case 20 To 29`

Comment: Thanks this worked. Also I had many unnecessary repetion of Cells(counter, 2) = grade.

Answer (score 1):

Try below. The code writes grade on next row as counter is increased before grade is written to the row cell. I moved the statement `counter = counter + 1` after select case, now all the rows get corresponding grade.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim mark As Single
    Dim grade As String
    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 1
    Do While counter < 10            
        mark = Cells(counter, 1).Value
        'To set the alignment to center
        Range("A1:B10").Select
            With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
        Select Case mark
            Case 0 To 20
            grade = "F"
            Cells(counter, 2) = grade
            Case 20 To 29
            grade = "E"
            Cells(counter, 2) = grade
            Case 30 To 39
            grade = "D"
            Cells(counter, 2) = grade
            Case 40 To 59
            grade = "C"
            Cells(counter, 2) = grade
            Case 60 To 79
            grade = "B"
            Cells(counter, 2) = grade
            Case 80 To 100
            grade = "A"
            Cells(counter, 2) = grade
            Case Else
            grade = "Error!"
            Cells(counter, 2) = grade
        End Select
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```