# Excel vlookup for teachers

Tags: excel, formula, calculation

How can you use vlookup to categorise your students marks either with a letter symbol or a level code?

As a teacher, you often use excel to store class test results, but may need to report actual marks or percentages as letter symbols or level codes. How can you automate this process?

Can you use vlookup?

Comment: Are you asking, if a student scored `84`, how to automatically fill in a "B" for that? (Assuming anything from `80` to `89` is a "B")?

Comment: This video link is useful: [Excel for Teachers - Grading](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRi5IdbOk8I) An answer to a similar question also serves as a good reminder that in order to use vlookup one should create a table in order to set out the rules for the formula - a place for the formula to look up the required details. [Another helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41600738/excel-multiple-cell-calculation?r=SearchResults)

Answer (score 3):

If you have numerical grades, and want to apply a Letter Grade, you can use `VLOOKUP()`.

Below, the formula goes in column C, and drag down.

Formula is:  `=VLOOKUP(B2,$A$9:$C$13,3,TRUE)`

[image]

So grades from 0 to 59 get an "F". (Yes, the second column shows 60, but it's really anything *up to* 60.

Anything from 60 to 69 gets a "D", etc.

Adjust/change as needed.